How to modify test clock of an existing Stripe customer/subscription?
Stripe documents are clear how to modify the test clock for a Stripe customer. They're here.
However, the documentations assume the user wants to create a new customer in Stripe. Hence step 2 is all about creating a new customer and associated subscription.
I'm trying to figure out how to modify the test clock of a pre-existing Stripe customer. For my testing purposes, the customer will be created via a UI on the front end. I then want to be able to fast forward the Stripe test clock of this user.
I've looked into updating the customer and subscription objects, but Stripe doesn't allow the test_clock field to be updated.
Any help would be appreciated.

This is not possible. Customers only get created in the scope of a Test Clock if test_clock is specified during creation, and it is not currently possible to retroactively associate a Test Clock to an existing customer.

Many thanks for your reply! I thought that might be the case as otherwise Stripe docs would probably have covered it.
I'll look into how else we might fast forward test clocks in our automated test suite.
Cheers!

This is possible. However, this will delete your test customer once you end the test clock.
Dashboard > Customers > Click on a customer > Subscriptions > Click on a subscription.
Should be a big purple banner displaying the text:
Run a simulation on this subscription. Model this subscription through time to test your integration. Only in test mode.
You can end the simulation by going into the clock.

Thanks for the reply.
Rereading my question I should have been clearer that I was looking to do this in a way that could be incorporated into automated tests, like via the Stripe API. But having asked Stripe support, I found out it just isn’t possible. The only option is to do it manually via the Stripe UI as you suggest.
